# Re-classifying a random matrix

Tags: r, matrix, raster

I am brand new to R and in some desperate need of help. I have created a random matrix and need to re-classify it. Each pixel is randomly generated from 0-255 and I need to able to classify the 0-255 digits into 8 classifications. How would I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated and I have placed my code below. I know I could use a raster but I am unsure on how to use them.

Thanks

> par(mar=rep(0,4))
>
> m=matrix(runif(100),10,10)
>
> image(m,axes=FALSE,col=grey(seq(0,1,length=255)))

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think your example adequately fit your description of the problem (since `runif` only ranges from 0-1 if the limits are not specified) so I modified it to fit the natural language features:

```
m=matrix(runif(100, 0, 255),10,10)
m[] <- findInterval(m, seq(0, 256, length=8) )

image(m,axes=FALSE,col=grey(seq(0,1,length=255)))
```

The "[]" with no indices preserves the matrix structure of the `m` object. The findInterval function lets you do the same sort of binning as cut, but it returns a numeric vector rather than the factor that `cut` would give.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer. However, when I run it through R studio it comes up with the error message "unexpected symbol in "m=matrix(runif(100,0,255),10,10 m"

Comment: There was an implicit linefeed in there that didn't survive my paste inot an unformatted section. Should deliver results now.